# checking free memory by free -h command , here what is difference between available and free memory?

Tags: ram, free

free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        2.1G        622M        362M        5.0G        4.9G
Swap:          7.5G        984M        6.5G

here free memory is shown as 622M and available memeory is 4.9G.

Answer (score 0):

Free memory is memory that is currently unused. Available memory is memory that the system is using for caches, but the data that it holds can be discarded easily (so without swapping to disk) and used for other purposes. Modern systems try to keep free memory relatively small because free/unused memory is just wasted.